# Stylus/tablet input device

Tags: webex

I need to make a WebCast presentation soon and need to do some "whiteboarding" during that WebCast. Does anyone have any stylus/tablet input device recommendations? Anyone ever used such an input device with WebEx's whiteboard feature?

rp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wacom http://www.wacom.com/index2.cfm
makes by far the best tablets I have ever used.  They come in a variety of prices with associated features.  If you want to be able to draw 'on-screen' they have the Cintiq, which is the most expensive, starting at $999 but definitely worth it.  For a cheaper more 'traditional' tablet there is Bambo and Intuos which start at $79, however with the Bambo and the Intuos there is quite a learning curve if your not already used to using tablets.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of people recommend Wacom. I've tried one, and it is really nice to use. To some extent, it really depends if you want only a tablet (no video feedback on the device), or a 'screen' (having video feedback, which I find nice but is also a bit pricey...).